# React-native Error : Invariant Violation "main" has not been registered, on iOS Simulator

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

i am trying to figure out why a react-native app build is running in Android devices as .apk but not in iOS devices as .ipa .The error on iOS simulator (from Expo) is :

"Invariant Violation "main" has not been registered.This can happen if : *Metro is run from the wrong folder.Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project. A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called."

Let me give some other informations. The project is react-native with pacjage.json

```
{
  "name": "Project",
  "version": "0.0.10",
  "server_id": 85,
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.4",
    "jest-expo": "^38.0.0",
    "react-native-scripts": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "android": "expo build:android",
    "ios": "expo build:ios",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^10.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "2.4.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "0.1.0-rc.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.0",
    "exp": "^57.2.1",
    "expo": "^38.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~8.2.1",
    "expo-secure-store": "~9.0.1",
    "graceful-fs": "^4.2.4",
    "hashmap": "^2.3.0",
    "i18next": "^19.6.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "native-base": "^2.13.12",
    "native-navigation": "^0.2.1",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "16.11.0",
    "react-i18next": "^11.7.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native-communications": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-display": "^1.0.8",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^2.0.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-spacer": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-localization": "^2.1.6",
    "react-native-maps": "0.27.1",
    "react-native-material-textfield": "^0.16.1",
    "react-native-md5": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^8.7.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-simple-radio-button": "^2.7.4",
    "react-native-slider": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-svg-uri": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.0.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.0",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.5.0",
    "react-navigation-is-focused-hoc": "^1.1.1",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.8.2",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.9.0",
    "react-timer-mixin": "^0.13.4",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "util": "^0.12.3"
  }
}
```

Some images :
[image: App Starts fine]

[image: Error]

[image: Extended Error]

The application Starts fine on iOS simulator but when the Downlad Javascipts are over it shows these errors. I am not familiar with React-native code or projects btw.

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of this error is that there is an exception thrown in your application before it's able to register itself. When a React Native application loads, there are two steps:

Load the JavaScript code, and if everything is successful, then your application will be registered. If there is any exception when loading the bundle then execution will be aborted and it will never reach the part where your application is registered.

Run the registered application. If loading the code failed, then the application won't be registered and you will see the error that is the subject of this page.
If you're in this situation, the error message you're seeing is a red herring, it's distracting you from the real error that led to the application not being registered.

Follow the expo docs troubleshooting guidelines about this error to find the real error:

https://docs.expo.io/troubleshooting/application-has-not-been-registered/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the android emulator. Perhaps the IOS Simulator has the same issue.

I discovered that my old app was installed in my android emulator.  This fixed it for me:

1. I uninstalled both the app and the new app from the emulator.
2. I killed both Metro and the emulator.
3. I restarted both Metro and the emulator.

It turns out the emulator retains each app it installs instead of starting out as a blank slate each time as I expected. When it starts up, it tries to load the app with the earliest install time. So, it kept trying to run my old app and contact the old Metro server instead of running my new app.